# Allow HTTPS connection to payseal.icicibank.com on port 443

Tags: java, linux, port, payment-gateway, redhat

I have a java application and I am integrating ICICI payment gateway to the my java application.

To integrate I have to allow HTTPS connection to payseal.icicibank.com on port 443.

How can I do this on linux server?

On my windows machine I have successfully integrated the gateway without configuring port 443 but on linux server I am finding some difficulties. I am getting the error

```
Error encountered. Error Code : 2 . Message Error while writing data. Transaction cannot be processed
```

How can I check that my linux server is allowing HTTPS connection to payseal.icicibank.com on port 443?

Thanks

Comment: slightly more sensible is `openssl s_client -connect payseal.icicibank.com:443` which will do sensible things like try to check if ssl is running on that port, and check things like certificates (this is often a reason for ssl connection problems in java - you may not have the cert chain, so it cannot be verified which drops connections almost immediately)

Comment: and when we test the connection, it indicates that openssl does not trust one of the signers in the chain, which will also undoubtably happen in java as well. search for questions/answers relating to adding CAs to the trust chain in java

Comment: @bmorris591 I have tried same command. It is showing "payseal.icicibank.com/443: Temporary failure in name resolution
"

Comment: @Petesh I have tried openssl command and I am getting this >getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
connect:errno=0

Comment: try running `nslookup payseal.icicibank.com` - looks like you don't have name resolution.

Comment: @bmorris591 I am getting this on running nslookup->> Server:         10.10.5.31
Address:        10.10.5.31#53

** server can't find payseal.icicibank.com: NXDOMAIN

Comment: telnet payseal.icicibank.com 443 is running perfectly on my windows machine

Comment: what should I do to resolve this problem. To allow port 443

Comment: Well, you don't have name resolution on the machine you are trying to run things on. Fix that and you'll be on your way...

Comment: Could you tell me how to do the name resolution?

Comment: my bad on the cert verification - it *does* verify! Setting up name resolution on  your system requires googling - is it a VM? host only networking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was the DNS problem on the server.